# Why Conditional attribute methods aren't allowed to return other than void

Tags: c#, .net

I've recently started to learn C# with a good book and now read about the `Conditional` attribute and the `#if` compiler directive.

I know the usage of the `#if` compiler directive:

```
#if DEBUG
public void foo(int value)
{ ... }
#endif
```

and of the `Conditional` attribute:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void foo(int value)
{ ... }
```

I also know that the code that is encased by the `#if` ... `#endif` statements doesn't reach the IL but the `Conditional` attribute code does and the calls to that function will be ommited.

**My question:**
Why there is the restriction about the `Conditional` attribute usage that functions marked with that attribute have to return `void` as [written here in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute)?

> You will get a compilation error in Visual Studio if you apply this attribute to a method that does not return void.

I already searched for information but found no explanation.

Comment: Id guess that because the call may not happen you cant have it set values, or, be used in decision making.. because it might not  exist..

Comment: If that were allowed, what would you expect the compiler to do here: `var x = someOtherMethod(foo());`

Comment: What exactly would you expect `i = f();` to assign to `i` when `f()` isn't called?

Comment: Yes sure I've got it and didn't thought about that earlier. It's so clear, easy and straight forward. Thank you all so much! Maybe someone would post that as an answer so that I can accept that.

Comment: @hvd: Do you want to post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @AndreKampling Sorry, I tried, but I can't find the words to turn it into anything anywhere near a *good* answer. If you're able to phrase it in such a way that it also helps future readers, feel free to self-answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler does not allow it, because if it *were* allowed, then the semantics of code like below would be undefined, or at best rather hard to understand:

```
var x = someMethod(foo());

[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
public int foo()
{
    return 42;
}
```

The `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute on a method means that both the method and any calls to the method are **omitted from the compiled code** if the `DEBUG` symbol is present.

But if the call to `foo()` - which returns a result - disappears from the compiled code, what to pass into `someMethod()`? Or if that call is then also removed, what to assign to **`x`**? How to guarantee that the local **`x`** even has a value, which would normally cause a compile error?

The .NET team decided not to go that way, instead they added a compile-time constraint that `[Conditional()]` methods must be `void` methods.